# How do I import a locally created package in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-pub

Say my projects' structures are as follows.

```
    contact_book <---(App)
    ├── bin
    │   └── contact_book.dart
    ├── contact_book.iml
    ├── lib
    │   ├── address.dart
    │   ├── email.dart
    │   ├── field.dart
    │   ├── functions.dart
    │   ├── person.dart
    │   └── phone_number.dart
    ├── pubspec.lock
    └── pubspec.yaml
    functions <---(Package)
    ├── bin
    │   └── lib
    │       └── functions.dart
    ├── functions.iml
    ├── pubspec.lock
    └── pubspec.yaml
```

Both folders are in the same directory. How do I call a function that's part of a .dart file that's in my other package? From reading the dart website, it seems like it's possible. That way I can write my own functions and use them across different projects. Did I just read that wrong and have to copy the files into my program?

Link: [Create Library Packages - Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/guides/libraries/create-library-packages)

Answer (score 8):

See https://www.dartlang.org/tools/pub/dependencies under "Path Packages".  You need only one copy, but you might need to "pub upgrade" whenever you change the included path.

Edit: "You don’t need to run pub every time you change the dependent package." And now I know!

Answer (score 7):

To use the local package "functions", which is located in the same directory as the project "contact_book", add the following code to the file "contact_book/pubspec.yaml":

```
dependencies:
  functions:
    path: ../functions
```